# Pure Python rational numbers module for 2.5

Tags: python, rational-numbers

Has anybody seen such a thing? Small self-sufficient modules are preferred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [fractions module](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) from 2.6 can be ripped out if necessary.  Grab fractions.py, numbers.py, and abc.py;  all pure python modules.

You can get the single files from here (2.6 branch, 2.7 does not work): 
http://hg.python.org/cpython/branches

Comment: True, i thought it would be much more difficult!

Comment: Note: This doesn't appear to work in the general case. E.g: fractions.Fraction(10) * 10 => Attribute Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'numerator'. int objects seem to have a numerator in Python 2.6, but not in Python 2.5. I'd be interested to know how others worked around this problem (I forced my literals to be fractions before using operators).

Comment: A better work-around is to change the definitions of 'forward' and 'reverse' in the '_operator_fallbacks' function to correctly handle int, and long. Hard to described in the comment due to limited format options, but something like: "elif isinstance(b, (int, long)): return monomorphic_operator(a, Fraction(b)"

Answer (score 9):

[SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) is a symbolic maths library written entirely in Python and has full support for rational numbers.  From the [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/tutorial.html):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a = Rational(1,2)

>>> a
1/2

>>> a*2
1

>>> Rational(2)**50/Rational(10)**50
1/88817841970012523233890533447265625
```

There is also GMP for Python ([GMPY](http://gmpy.sourceforge.net/)) which, while not pure Python, is probably more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. SymPy's Rational is nice, if a little too intertwined with other parts of the library.

Answer (score 3):

One more thing to try is [Rat.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release25-maint/Demo/classes/Rat.py?rev=51333&view=markup) from demo folder in Python 2.5 maintenance branch. If i understand correctly, it is the daddy of 2.6 `fractions`. It's a single module without dependencies.

```
>>> from Rat import rat
>>> rat(1) / rat(3)
Rat(1,3)
>>> rat(1, 3) ** 2
Rat(1,9)
```

**UPDATE**: Nah, `fractions.py` is about 2.5 times faster for my task.