# Can I bring a Python 2.6 module (fractions) to Python 2.5?

Tags: python, import, python-module, fractions

My question really says it all: can I do this? I saw something about being able to supposedly import future modules online, but I'm not sure I really understood it correctly.  The module I want to bring to 2.5 is fractions.  Is there any way to do this, or is there another module that is native to 2.5 that would replace the fractions module?

Keep in mind that the only reason I am in need of the fractions module is for the ability to convert decimals to fractions.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/329453/222914) says you can, though the comments mention that not everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the source! Just download the source and modify it as needed for 2.5 I also some this: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090610101000AAerKHj

Or you could use SymPy: [Pure Python rational numbers module for 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329333/pure-python-rational-numbers-module-for-2-5)